# Trouble setting x_tick value with python scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe `avg_temp` with 2 columns. I Want to so a scatter plot of these two columns and with the x_ticks being the index values.

```
High_Avg    Low_Avg
2014    28.516129032258064  9.419354838709678
2015    32.193548387096776  16.516129032258064
2016    35.32258064516129   18.548387096774192
2017    39.29032258064516   24.483870967741936
2018    31.548387096774192  13.903225806451612
```

I use the following code:

```
avg_plot=avg_temp.plot(style=['o','rx'])
avg_plot.set_xticklabels(avg_temp.index)
```

The resultant graph looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the index values to exactly align with the scatter plot values.
How do I do it?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data.  Post the data as text or the code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.plot(style=['o','rx'])
_ = plt.xticks(df.index)
```

OR

```
ax = df.plot(style=['o','rx'])
_ = ax.set_xticks(df.index)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. Got this error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: use your data frame instead of df.